# Passing multiple values from one html page to another html page

Tags: jquery

I have made some calculation using jquery in Page1.html by getting the value from inputboxes using get function and store the variable tax6 and its value by setting in inputbox8 using set function of jquery. I have used window.location.href to pass the value of inputbox8 and inputbox4 in variable tax7 in Page2.html. In Page2.html i have used document.url.indexof but i am not getting the value in inputbox9 and inputbox10. It simply concate the values. Kindly help me out.

```html
Page1.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get a time-based greeting:</p>
INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput" value="">
DEDUCTION: <input type="text" id="myinput1" value="" readonly>
GROSS INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput2" value="" readonly>
TAX: <input type="text" id="myinput3" value=""readonly>
NET INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput4" value="">

<button id="click1">CALCULATE NET INCOME</button><br><br>

NET INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput5" value="">
AGRI INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput6" value="">
OTHER SOURCE: <input type="text" id="myinput7" value="">
TOTAL INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput8" value="">

<button id="click2">CALCULATE TOTAL INCOME</button>

<button id="click3">next</button>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#click1").click(function a(){
        
  myfunction();
        
    });

   
function myfunction() {
var tax, tax1, tax2;
var inc = $("#myinput").val();
 alert(inc);
  $("#myinput1").val(10000);

  tax1 = inc - 10000;

  $("#myinput2").val(tax1);
     
     if (tax1 <=250000) {
        tax = "0";
     } 
 
 else if (tax1 >250000 && tax1<=500000) {
 tax = (tax1 - 250000)*5/100;
  }

 else if (tax1 >500000 && tax1<=1000000) {
 tax = 12000 + ((tax1 - 500000)*20/100);
  }

 else { tax = 112000 + ((tax1 - 1000000)*30/100);
  }

 $("#myinput3").val(tax);

 
 tax2 =  tax1 - tax;
 

 $("#myinput4").val(tax2);
 $("#myinput5").val(tax2);
  
 
}

 $("#click2").click(function b(){

     
  myfunction1();
        
    });
 function myfunction1() {
var tax4, tax5, tax6, tax7;
  var ni=$("#myinput4").val();

 
 var tax4 = $("#myinput6").val();
 var tax5 = $("#myinput7").val();


m=parseInt(ni); 
k=parseInt(tax4);
l=parseInt(tax5);
 tax6 = k + l+m;

 $("#myinput8").val(tax6);  

 $("#click3").click(function c(){
  window.location.href="getset-index2.html?tax7="+$('#myinput8').val()+$('#myinput4').val();
 });

 }
 

});
</script>

</body>
</html>


Page2.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>


<body>
TOTAL INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput9" value="" readonly>
NET INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput10" value="">
EMI CAR: <input type="text" id="myinput11" value="">
TOTAL NET INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput12" value="">

<button id="click4">CALCULATE NET INCOME</button><br><br>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $("#click4").click(function d(){
 

   myfunction2();
 });
  function myfunction2() {
   
var x, tax8, tax9, tax10;

var x = document.URL.indexOf('?tax7=');
 
 $("#myinput9").val(x); 

}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using `document.URL.indexOf('?tax7=')` which give u a position of string in url.

You can check following steps to find a value.

```
var url_string = window.location.href; // give u current url
var url = new URL(url_string); // create url string
var c = url.searchParams.get("tax7"); // search your parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed your code as below. 
if you want to inputbox9 and inputbox10 values, then you want to send it separately.

```
window.location.href="2.html?tax7="+$('#myinput8').val()+"&tax10="+$('#myinput4').val();
```

if you want to get url paramter values use above modification

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        tax9 = urlParams.get('tax7');
    tax10 = urlParams.get('tax10');
    $("#myinput9").val(tax9);   
    $("#myinput10").val(tax10);
```

You can find full code below.

Page1.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get a time-based greeting:</p>
INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput" value="">
DEDUCTION: <input type="text" id="myinput1" value="" readonly>
GROSS INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput2" value="" readonly>
TAX: <input type="text" id="myinput3" value=""readonly>
NET INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput4" value="">

<button id="click1">CALCULATE NET INCOME</button><br><br>

NET INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput5" value="">
AGRI INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput6" value="">
OTHER SOURCE: <input type="text" id="myinput7" value="">
TOTAL INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput8" value="">

<button id="click2">CALCULATE TOTAL INCOME</button>

<button id="click3">next</button>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click1").click(function a(){

        myfunction();

    });


function myfunction() {
var tax, tax1, tax2;
var inc = $("#myinput").val();
    alert(inc);
     $("#myinput1").val(10000);

     tax1 = inc - 10000;

     $("#myinput2").val(tax1);

        if (tax1 <=250000) {
        tax = "0";
     } 

    else if (tax1 >250000 && tax1<=500000) {
    tax = (tax1 - 250000)*5/100;
     }

    else if (tax1 >500000 && tax1<=1000000) {
    tax = 12000 + ((tax1 - 500000)*20/100);
     }

    else { tax = 112000 + ((tax1 - 1000000)*30/100);
     }

    $("#myinput3").val(tax);


    tax2 =  tax1 - tax;


    $("#myinput4").val(tax2);
    $("#myinput5").val(tax2);


}

 $("#click2").click(function b(){


        myfunction1();

    });
    function myfunction1() {
var tax4, tax5, tax6, tax7;
     var ni=$("#myinput4").val();


    var tax4 = $("#myinput6").val();
    var tax5 = $("#myinput7").val();


m=parseInt(ni); 
k=parseInt(tax4);
l=parseInt(tax5);
    tax6 = k + l+m;

    $("#myinput8").val(tax6);       

    $("#click3").click(function c(){
        window.location.href="2.html?tax7="+$('#myinput8').val()+"&tax10="+$('#myinput4').val();
    });

    }


});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Page2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>


<body>
TOTAL INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput9" value="" readonly>
NET INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput10" value="">
EMI CAR: <input type="text" id="myinput11" value="">
TOTAL NET INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput12" value="">

<button id="click4">CALCULATE NET INCOME</button><br><br>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#click4").click(function d(){


            myfunction2();
    });
        function myfunction2() {

var x, tax8, tax9, tax10;


var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    tax9 = urlParams.get('tax7');
    tax10 = urlParams.get('tax10');
    $("#myinput9").val(tax9);   
    $("#myinput10").val(tax10); 

}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```